# Get a list of elements, from a sortedlist, using a list of keys, using LINQ, in C#

Tags: c#, linq

With a sorted list:

```
[11] = "a"
[22] = "b"
[35] = "c"
[40] = "d"
[45] = "e"
```

and a list of keys:

```
[35, 40, 45]
```

how can I get the data matching the list of keys.
the output should be:

```
["c", "d", "e"]
```

Edit:

The type is SortedList()
the class 'SomeClass' contains the key value as well.
an example would be:

```
class SomeClass
{
    string Key;
    ... some other fields
}
```

my attempt was:

```
MyList.Values.Where(_ => keys.Contains(_.key)).ToList();
```

but this is not using the index.

This works as long as all elements can be found:

```
    public class A
    {
        public string Key;
        public string SomeValue;
    }

        var l = new SortedList<string, A>
        {
            ["aa"] = new A { Key = "aa" },
            ["bb"] = new A { Key = "bb" },
            ["cc"] = new A { Key = "cc" },
            ["dd"] = new A { Key = "dd" }
        };

        var ids = new List<string> { "bb", "cc" };

        var r = ids.Select(i => l[i]).ToList();
```

Following the advice of using TryGetValue is good, but I'm not sure how to combine it with select.

Comment: That's a pretty straight-forward LINQ statement: `list.Where(item => keys.Contains(item.Key)).Select(item => item.Value);`

Comment: @itsme86 this is not how that interview question is answered... must be O(n) and not O(n^2) as your suggestion - should carefully walk both in parallel to match

Comment: it's not an interview question :D I'm moving a small dataset from a database to ram, so I'm trying rebuild the basic queries that were done in mongo to straight code. It's about 20k records, so while not huge speed still matters.

Comment: What does your `SomeClass` look like? You need to provide a minimal and complete example that can be used to verify.

Comment: @Thomas - the accepted answer makes no sense based on so much emphasis on having both arrays sorted... Consider editing your question to match accepted answer. (Consider also clarifying that this is not an interview question so performance does not matter).

Comment: where is the confusion? the context is that it is the backend of an aviation app and there are constant lookups for plane info; since all the info holds in memory, I removed the mongo table and I'm trying to provide the objects matching a list of ids as fast as possible. I think the question fits that context and the answer fit precisely the question. where do you see a mismatch?

Comment: @Thomas I did not realize that you talk about `SortedList` and not "sorted list". Still I think you should comment that performance does not matter (especially since O(len_list_of_ids) solution `ids.Select(i => l[i]).ToList();` is provided in the question already and accepted is O(len_values * len_list_of_ids) ).

Comment: but performance does matter, which is why I did mongo->ram and also why I'm using a sorted list instead of just doing a where in an unsorted list; unfortunately, I didn't provide enough details at the beginning of the question so it became an iterative process where I added chunks of information as questions came, so the scope got narrowed progressively. In practice, the data is never updated once it is loaded, but is queried in read-only fashion quite a lot, so SortedList seems to be a good candidate.

Comment: "but performance does matter" - so that's why you've accepted answer that has worse performance than you had provided in question :)... (Note that the question is not asking about whether reading from DB is slow or not, it simply asks about one particular operation that has nothing to do with DB - and it looks like for that particular step performance does not matter, presumably because you already got gains you need from caching DB in memory... )

Comment: The one is the question is faster, but it fails when the id list contains elements that are not in the data. The only improvement I can think about would be to sort the list of ids, so looking for them would require a single scan of the list keys; what else do you have in mind?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, this will work?

```
var list = new SortedList<string, SomeClass>
{
    ["aa"] = new SomeClass { Key = "aa" },
    ["bb"] = new SomeClass { Key = "bb" },
    ["cc"] = new SomeClass { Key = "cc" },
    ["dd"] = new SomeClass { Key = "dd" }
};

var ids = new List<string> { "bb", "cc" };

var results = list.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Key)).ToList();
```

If you need only the `SomeClass` list:

```
var someClassList = list.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Key)).Select(y => y.Value);
```

Comment: If `ids` was sorted (and particularly if it was large) I'd strongly suggested using `BinarySearch` over `Contains`. `BinarySearch` helps you achieve a performance benefit since it tells you where to start your _next_ search.

Comment: @mjwills Better yet, make `ids` a `HashSet<string>` so that `Contains` runs in constant time.

Comment: @juharr Sometimes `BinarySearch` will outperform it (since you avoid the cost of creating the `HashSet`), and you can search only a subset of the list. But yes, `HashSet` will likely perform and scale much better than the current answer.

Comment: @mjwills Yes it really depends on the sizes of the lists whether O(m + n) or O(m log n) would be better.  It's much more likely that your answer is better as I'd expect a list of lookup ids to be smaller than the collection the lookup is done on.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the `SortedList` and the size of `ids`, the below code maybe worth considering (to avoid iterating over the entirety of `SortedList`). *It will be particularly beneficial if `ids` is small and `list` is large.*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new SortedList<string, SomeClass>
            {
                ["aa"] = new SomeClass { Key = "aa" },
                ["bb"] = new SomeClass { Key = "bb" },
                ["cc"] = new SomeClass { Key = "cc" },
                ["dd"] = new SomeClass { Key = "dd" }
            };

            var ids = new List<string> { "bb", "cc" };

            var results = ids.Select(x =>
            {
                list.TryGetValue(x, out var matching);
                return matching;
            }).Where(z => z != null);

            // Output to show the results
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results.Select(z => z.Key)));
        }
    }
}
```